# Does there exist an English translation of the book Théorie Des Distributions by Laurent Schwartz?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Does there exist an English translation of the book *Théorie Des Distributions* by Laurent Schwartz? The theory of Distributions as it is presented in modern books is very much evolved and for a beginner it is difficult to comprehend the motivation behind it. The father of the subject; Laurent Schwartz wrote his treatise in french. A few pages of the original book was translated into english. It is much easier to comprehend the motivation behind the various concepts,in this book. That's why I wanted to know if there is a complete translated version of the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I am aware of. However, in 1952 Israel Halperin published his *Introduction to the Theory of Distributions* (University of Toronto Press), based upon Schwartz's lectures on that subject.

Comment: thanks. it was a useful information